# How to simulate test data to a database?

Tags: testing, sql

I've created a service application that import orders from an SQL database. Right now I'm manually entering the data into the database, but in release a 3rd party application will export orders to the database.

[image: overview]

For now, while in testing, I'd like to have a test software to simulate orders coming in and out of the database. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not write the code to emulate the orders coming in, or capturing production data periodically to use in test?

Comment: Yes that's true. But wonder if there is a generic one?

Comment: @MatsGausdal: I am not sure what you mean by "generic solution", but if you are looking for a tool which magically knows which records need to be inserted or deleted to simulate incoming and outgoing orders in the specific schema of your DB, the answer is "no, there is no such tool, you have to develop one by yourself".

Comment: No, in the tool one could manually enter what data to put in, and then have a counter or random variable for every entry that is published every x seconds. Alright I'll just write it myself.

Comment: *"in the tool one could manually enter what data to put in, and then have a counter or random variable for every entry that is published every x seconds"* - that does not sound like a generic requirement to me, but a very specific one - so yes, you will most probably have to write your own specific solution.

Comment: What, exactly, are you testing? Are you testing how client code reacts to data changes? In that case you may not even need a database.

Comment: Yes @JohnDouma. I'd like to test how the service reacts to new orders being added to the database. I have a replica test database set up, and want to add test orders to it. It is one table that cointains orderId, orderNumber, dateAdded, dataChanged, qty, articleNumber etc.

Comment: How does your service get the updates? Does it periodically query the database or is some notification sent?

Comment: It periodically queries the database.

Comment: For each test case, mock the database interface, if possible. Otherwise, have a set of records for each test case and load those into your test database before each test is run. As suggested by others you can extract the data you need from a production database. You don't, however, need to load the whole database.

Comment: It is this loading part that was my original question. Right now I'm loading it manually, writing row for row of orders. Looking for a way to load it with test data more efficiently. Edit: I'm doing it manually in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: If you are using a tool like JUnit, you should be able to run insert statements in your setup code and delete statements, if necessary, in your teardown code. You only load the data you need so it is very efficient.

Comment: @JohnDouma Thank you. From JUnit, I found NUnit for C# and it looks like it might be a solution to test against the SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get the data for test in is the same way that it will get in in production, because its the most realistic.

So the question here is how exactly does this third part software get its data in? inserts, a sproc, an API, SSIS? use the same method to insert your test data.

If you don't know or cant tell, then you could run the tool and check the database log, or monitor the network traffic. perhaps you can even rerun the transactions

Comment: Why would it matter how the 3rd party software gets its data in? Orders are added to the database and the service application imports the orders from the database. Instead of adding the orders manually, I'd like to have a tool where I can select the database and the table, and then simulate 50 orders coming in during 2 mins. So during the 2 mins with equal interval, orderNumbers are incremented, ArticleNumbers are randomly selected from the Article table, the qty is a random integer between 1 and 50.

Comment: because you want to ensure the the orders look exactly like real ones. if you fake the insert you may miss something. Also the process of inserting make break you code, for example deadlocks

Comment: @Ewan Unit tests are meant to test specific areas of the code. If we are testing how our service reacts to changes in code then it is perfectly okay to mock the data. I have seen too many slow builds because of developers who didn't grasp the idea of modularity and overcomplicated their tests.

Comment: @JohnDouma sure, but this question specifically asks about getting data into the database

Comment: if you were mocking you would mock whatever data layer retrieves the data from the database

Comment: @Ewan Yes, but for testing. There is a thread under his question that clarifies what is being tested.

Comment: well sorry, but i think for this question my answer is the best. You have a 3rd party tool accessing your db doing god knows what, you want to make sure your program _works_ in live, not _should work_ sure you can add unit tests as well, but id want to have this integration test running and passing before i rolled out.